# Require protocol implementor to mark function with @objc

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm playing around with `UIMenuController` where I can add a menu item which takes a `#selector` in its init.

Now I may grab the call in several different places and so want to write a protocol to make sure every place I want to grab the action from the responder chain implements the correct function signature.

My problem is, how do I require protocol implementors to add `@objc` to a function of the protocol? Otherwise it won't be called.

```
protocol PrintToConsoleProtocol {
    func printToConsole()
}

extension PDFView: PrintToConsoleProtocol {
    // PDFView conforms to PrintToConsoleProtocol without @objc!
    // So protocol does not make sure the implementor will be callable
    // despite having adopted it.
    @objc func printToConsole() {
        print("Printing to console.. from PDFView!")
    }
}
```

Code to add a menu entry:

```
let printToConsole = UIMenuItem(
    title: "Print To Console",
    action: #selector(PrintToConsoleProtocol.printToConsole)
)
UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [printToConsole]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@objc` before the `protocol`-keyword to make it an objc-protocol and adopting it interprets all functions in the protocol now present in the implementor as having `@objc` before it.

```
@objc protocol PrintToConsoleProtocol {
    func printToConsole()
}

extension PDFView: PrintToConsoleProtocol {
    func printToConsole() {
        print("Printing to console.. from PDFView!")
    }
}
```